# Significance of Ratri in Navaratri

Tags: devi, durga, nava-durga

The nine Nights popularly Navaratri is popularly celebrated for Ma Durga, Is there any reason why is it named "ratri" which means "Nights", and the significance of the number nine? I know there are Nine forms of Durga worshipped on each day of Navaratri? But there are many avatars of Durga, why only these nine?